# My close button does not work with jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin full screen search with two separate buttons. One                                            button to open the full screen search in the header of my site and the other one to close the full screen search inside the div. The open button is working fine with the jquery animation, but the close button isn't working with the jquery animation.

So I want to close the div using the jquery animation slide effect.

html code :

```
<div id="full-screen-search">
<button type="button" class="close" id="full-screen-search-close">X</button>
</div>
```

jquery code for the animation :

```
$("#btn_show").click(function(){
$("#full-screen-search").animate ({ width: 'show' });  
}); 

$("#full-screen-search-close").click(function(){
$("#full-screen-search").animate ({ width: 'hide' });     
});
```

jquery code of the plugin :

```
     // When the document is ready...
     jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    
// ... display the Full Screen search when:
// 1. The user focuses on a search field, or
// 2. The user clicks the Search button
$( 'form[role=search] input, form[role=search] button' ).on( 'focus, click', function( event ) {
    // Prevent the default action
    event.preventDefault();

    // Display the Full Screen Search
    $( '#full-screen-search' ).addClass( 'open' );

    // Focus on the Full Screen Search Input Field
    $( '#full-screen-search input' ).focus();
} );

// Hide the Full Screen search when the user clicks the close button
$( '#full-screen-search button.close' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // Prevent the default event
    event.preventDefault();

    // Hide the Full Screen Search
    $( '#full-screen-search' ).removeClass( 'open' );
} );

 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `show` and/or `hide` as a width value. The width must be either a percent, or a number with some unit (eg. `300px` or `25vw`)

Note that in the below example we show/hide the button in a callback - that is, a function that is run *after* the animation completes.

```js
$("#btn_show").hide();

$("#btn_show").click(function(){
  $("#full-screen-search").show().animate ({ width: '100%' }, function(){
    $("#btn_show").hide();
  });
}); 

$("#full-screen-search-close").click(function(){
  $("#full-screen-search").animate ({ width: '0px' }, function(){$("#full-screen-search").hide()}); 
  $("#btn_show").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
*{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
#full-screen-search{width:100%;height:80px;background:wheat;border:1px solid orange;}
#full-screen-search-close{position:absolute;top:1px;right:1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn_show">click</button>
<div id="full-screen-search">
  <button type="button" class="close" id="full-screen-search-close">X</button>
</div>
```